# Three.js object definition not defining

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am working my way through a set of tutorials and have come across an error I cant figure out...

I know it is probably me being blind due to my lazy upbringing with IDE's that have red underlines for syntax errors but I kinda need this done soon!

The error is 
TypeError: Tetris.boundingBoxConfig is undefined
file:///C:/Users/Timmy/Documents/Emergent%20Tech/Tetris/js/tetris.js
Line 127

here i define Tetris.boundingBoxConfig

```
var boundingBoxConfig = {
    width: 360,
    height: 360,
    depth: 1200,
    splitX: 6,
    splitY: 6,
    splitZ: 20
  };

  Tetris.boundingBoxConfig = boundingBoxConfig;
```

and here is line 127

```
mesh.position.x = (x - Tetris.boundingBoxConfig.splitX/2)*Tetris.blockSize + Tetris.blockSize/2;
```

if you need more of the code let me know and I will edit.  Any Help would be much appreciated! please only constructive criticism

**EDIT** Definition of Tetris Object

```
var Tetris = {};
```

There was a second suggested way of doing it like this:

```
window.Tetris = window.Tetris || {};
```

but i don't really get how that way works

**EDIT 2**

Not sure if this helps the clarify the issue

```
var boundingBox = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.CubeGeometry(
    boundingBoxConfig.width, boundingBoxConfig.height, boundingBoxConfig.depth, 
    boundingBoxConfig.splitX, boundingBoxConfig.splitY,         boundingBoxConfig.splitZ), 
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffaa00, wireframe: true } )
);
Tetris.scene.add(boundingBox);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to me using local files in Firefox.  I knew that Chrome had security issues when loading the files from a local disk so went with Firefox believing there was not a similar problem due to other projects working.  I was wrong.

Lesson: Never use local files always use a server.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Tetris function, try changing

`Tetris.boundingBoxConfig = boundingBoxConfig;`

To

`this.boundingBoxConfig = { //your definition };`

so that your property becomes public.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i am afraid that it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Could you please include the code where you have defined the "Tetris" object? (ie var Tetris blah blah blah)

Comment: Hard to give an exact answer, but hopefully this will put you on the right track: use "console.log(data);" to output the value of tetris and tetris.boundingBoxConfig throughout your code to see where it is being set to null or something.  check right after you define it to make sure the definition took.  also here is some info on undefined errors in JS: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/

Comment: console.log(Tetris.boundingBoxConfig); output each variable as expected, no NULL values

Comment: Comments should be posted as comments, not answers.